# Angular directive scope - template include vs inline transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angular directive for displaying a modal window.  It can accept the contents either inline between the HTML tags, or be pointed to a template.  When using this directive I seem to have normal access to the `$scope` when I am using the transcluded inline version of this directive, but when I use a template I do not.

What am I missing here?  I've made a smaller sample directive that has the same behavior.

**Demo:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/ahezfaxj/2

**Inline Content Usage**

```
<ang-test show="showBoolean">
  <p>Content here!</p>
</ang-test>
```

**Template Usage**

```
<ang-test show="showBoolean" template="'myTemplate.html'"></ang-test>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("angTest", function () {
    return {
        template: function () {
            return "<div class='test-container'>" +
                " <div ng-if='show && template' ng-include='template'></div>" +
                " <div ng-if='show && !template' ng-transclude></div>" +
                "</div>";
        },
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            template: "@",
            show: "="
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
            if(value){
                $element[0].style.display="block";
            }else{
                $element[0].style.display="none";
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo below. You created isolated scope in your directive thus your directive scope is not this same as controller $scope. But you can add as well **thing** to your directive scope like in example below.

I hope that will help.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("BaseCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.thing = "Hello!";
  $scope.showOne=false;
  $scope.showTwo=false;
});

app.directive("angTest", function () {
    return {
        template: function () {
            return "<div class='test-container'>" +
    " <div ng-if='show && template' ng-include='template'></div>" +
    " <div ng-if='show && !template' ng-transclude></div>" +
    "</div>";
        },
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            template: "@",
            show: "=",
            thing:'@'
            
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
            //Show/hide when `show` changes
            $scope.$watch("show", function (value) {
                if(value){
                    $element[0].style.display="block";
                }else{
                    $element[0].style.display="none";
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.test-container{
    padding:5px;
    background: #EEE;
}
.transcluded {
    color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
      Outside Directive: <strong>{{thing}}</strong>
      
      <hr />
      
      <button type="button" ng-click="showOne=!showOne">Toggle One</button>
      <ang-test show="showOne">
          <p class="transcluded">Inside Included Directive: <strong>--> thing transcluded-->{{thing}}</strong></p>
      </ang-test>      
      
      <hr />
      
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">
        <p>Inside Template Directive: <strong>thing from directive scope -->{{thing}}</strong></p>
      </script>
      
      <button type="button" ng-click="showTwo=!showTwo" >Toggle Two</button>
      <ang-test show="showTwo" template="myTemplate" thing="{{thing}}"></ang-test>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I just pass the entire scope through without having to specify it inside the directive?  I don't want to have to specify all possible scope variables for my project in a directive.

Comment: You don't have to create isolated scope...(just don't define it in your directive) but you have to be very careful when you create your directive because look here what can happens http://fiddle.jshell.net/ahezfaxj/5/